# Зациклить массив, полученный из базы данных

Tags: php

Есть функция, которая возвращает массив из базы данных

```
function selected($table, $data = 0) {
    $podkluchenie = podkluchenie();

    if($data != '') {
        $where = "WHERE ";
        foreach($data as $key => $value) {
            $where .= "$key = '$value' AND ";
        }

        $where = chop($where," AND ");
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table $where";
    $result = mysqli_query($podkluchenie, $sql);
    while($arr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        return $arr;
    }
}
```

И есть строка, которую необходимо зациклить с помощью `foreach`, но он ругается

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'fio'

```
$result = selected('employees');

<?php foreach ($result as $resultat) {?>
<tr><td><a href="employees.php?chief_id=<?php echo $resultat['id']; ?>">
<?php echo $resultat['fio']; ?></a></td></tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Помогите разобраться

Comment: Сделайте `var_dump($result);` после `$result=selected('employees');` и будет понятно, что за структуру вам запрос вернул.

Comment: @Doofy Возвращает массив array(2) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["fio"]=> string(38) "Иванов Иван Иванович" }

Comment: @AndrewLyu, пичалька, я ушёл за мороженкой

Comment: @Visman Возвращает массив array(2) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["fio"]=> string(38) "Иванов Иван Иванович" }

Answer (score 1):

Если брать по вашей логике, то:

```
<?php
$result[0]['id'] = 'RESULT_ID';
$result[0]['fio'] = 'RESULT_FIO';
?>
<?php foreach ($result as $resultat) {?>
<tr><td><a href="employees.php?chief_id=<?php echo $resultat['id']; ?>">
<?php echo $resultat['fio']; ?></a></td></tr>
<?php } ?>
```

этот код работает без ошибок, косяк в самом ответе от запроса

Comment: возвращает массив Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [fio] => Иванов Иван Иванович
)

Comment: @AndrewLyu а ну все, тогда нашли косяк, ответ должен быть Array(array( [id] => 1 [fio] => Иванов Иван Иванович ))

Comment: Если у вас ответ вида array( [id] => 1 [fio] => Иванов Иван Иванович), то это $result['id] = 1, $result['fio'] = '2', тогда FOREACH пробегает по элементам массива, и в RESULT - у вас только значения строки (1,2). И следовательно ошибка потому-что, $RESULTAT - строка, а код хочет массива.

Comment: Как-то странно вы форму выводите. Можно же в одних тегах `<?php ... ?>` а внутри всё остальное, [уот так уот](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Keu4n.png)

Comment: @Doofy а еще лучше юзать паттерны проектирования, а то я так понял в одном коде объеденил MVC. ну пусть учатся :)

Comment: @Manitikyl А какой в итоге выход из этой ситуации?